# Muting, unmuting and whispering someone in a chat room in socket.io

Tags: socket.io, chat

I have the tutorial of socket.io chat room done. I want to be able to mute someone (no longer receive his chat) in the chat room by typing `/mute *person-name*` and then unmute him by typing `/unmute *person-name*` and chat someone specific by typing `/whisper *person-name*`

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

To handle the mute command use string operations to check if the first letter of the message is "/", and if there is a "mute" in the command. You will need a list of users to loop through to check who is being muted.

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            if(msg.charAt(0) == "/") {
                //Process command

                command = msg.substring(1, msg.length);

                //unmute
                if (command.includes("unmute")) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < your_user_list.length; i++) {
                        if (command.includes(your_user_list[i].username)) {
                            your_user_list[i].muted = false;
                        }
                    }
                } //mute
                else if (command.includes("mute")) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < your_user_list.length; i++) {
                        if (command.includes(your_user_list[i].username)) {
                            your_user_list[i].muted = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //Send message
                console.log(socket.username + ": " + msg);
                io.emit('chat message', socket.username + ": " + msg);
            }
        });
```

To mute somebody add a member variable to the socket

```
socket.muted = true;
```

And then check if the user is muted, every time they submit a message like this.

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            if(!socket.muted) {
                //Allow the user to chat

                if(msg.charAt(0) == "/") {
                    //Process command

                    command = msg.substring(1, msg.length);

                    //unmute
                    if (command.includes("unmute")) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < your_user_list.length; i++) {
                            if (command.includes(your_user_list[i].username)) {
                                your_user_list[i].muted = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } //mute
                    else if (command.includes("mute")) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < your_user_list.length; i++) {
                            if (command.includes(your_user_list[i].username)) {
                                your_user_list[i].muted = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //Send message
                    console.log(socket.username + ": " + msg);
                    io.emit('chat message', socket.username + ": " + msg);
                }
            }
            else {
                //Tell them they are muted
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me